# Application-defined or Object-defined error (comma) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Getting an error:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

for this line in my VBA Code.

The debugger is highlighting the comma right before numS.

How can I fix this?

(xdate is of Date type but all other variables are Integer type)

```
Range(Cells(dRow + gTime, 5), Cells(rowCount, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[1]=" & "DATEVALUE(""" & (xdate) & """)" & "," & (numS) & ", """")"
```

Comment: Posting a single line of code without any of the surrounding context isn't useful. Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see the code that is before the line you indicated.

Comment: your issue must be in the Range definition: double check the actual values of `dRow`, `gTime` and `RowCount`